# How to create an array of lines of double quoted strings in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, double-quotes

I'm trying to split a line with double quoted strings into an array:

input.txt:

```
"ABC" "This is TEST 1" "12.3.0"    
"AC" "This is TEST 221" "123"    
"CX" "This is TEST 16" "123.2"    
"LM" "This is TEST 9000" "123.6.6.1"
```

What I'm hoping to be the outcome for each line:

```
print $a[0] $a[1] $a[2]

ABC This is TEST 1 12.3.0
```

How best to grab each string per line? I'm trying to do this via command line and/or a shell script

Update:
To help reduce complexity, I've updated my "input.txt" file as follows:
input.txt:

```
'ABC' 'This is TEST 1' '12.3.0'    
'AC' 'This is "TEST" 221' '123'    
'CX' 'This is TEST 16' '123.2'    
'LM' 'This is TEST 9000' '123.6.6.1'
```

All the double quotes have been replaced with Single quotes, other that the ones with-in a value.

Comment: Use `${a[0]}` to access an array element.

Comment: Is it possible for there to be escaped double-quotes inside a value, e.g. `"This \"is a\" test"`?

Comment: My Bad. Let me clarify, how to I put each double quoted sting into an array.

Comment: Yes. Some values are as such:
"This is a "TEST" 221"

Comment: Unescaped nested quotes?

Comment: So there are embedded double-quotes which are not escaped? That poses an unusual challenge. Is it guaranteed that (1) every second-level double-quote is balanced, i.e. with both an opening and closing second-level double-quote, (2) the opening second-level double-quote is never followed by a space character, and (3) there are no third-level double-quotes? If all 3 of those points are guaranteed to be satisfied in all cases then I think this will be possible to do in a foolproof way, otherwise, probably not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using bash:

```
IFS='"' a=("ABC" "This is TEST1" "12.3.0")
```

should almost work.  The indexes will be off, with empty entries, but:

```
 while IFS='"' read -a a; do 
    echo ${a[1]} ${a[3]} ${a[5]}; done < input
```

gets you most of the way there.  Keep in mind  that this is pretty fragile.

Comment: This will change `IFS` for the entire shell/script.

Comment: No it doesn't. Try it. `(declare -p IFS; IFS='"' a=("foo bar"); declare -p a IFS)`

Comment: Yeah. Assignment to `IFS` is tricky like that. `IFS='"' read` *is* locally scoped though.

Comment: @EtanReisner In my defense, I did say this was fragile!

Comment: Also if you are going to using `read -a` and read-scoped `IFS` is probably a better path.